# Spring boot: put api version on method level before the uri collection name

Tags: spring-boot

In Spring boot, I am slightly annoyed with how it is straightforward to make the version appear in the url in different ways, except the one that makes sense the most.
Spending more time on this silly issue than I would care to admit.

Currently, working url looks like this:

http://localhost:8080/api/sectors/v1.0

What I want is to have the url appear like this:

http://localhost:8080/api/v1.0/sectors

But note that I want to declare the version appear on the **method declaration**.
If one method changes, I don't want to replace my entire controller, just the method.

Current implementation:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/sectors")
public class SectorController {

    private final SectorRepository sectorRepository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public SectorController(SectorRepository sectorRepository, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.sectorRepository = sectorRepository;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }


    @GetMapping(value = "/v1.0")
    @ResponseStatus(OK)
    public Flux<SectorDto> getAllSectors() {
        Flux<SectorEntity> sectors = sectorRepository.findAll();
        return sectors.map(sector -> modelMapper.map(sector, SectorDto.class));
    }
}
```

Note: I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `@RequestMapping` and `@GetMapping` to the following

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class SectorController {

    private final SectorRepository sectorRepository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public SectorController(SectorRepository sectorRepository, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.sectorRepository = sectorRepository;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "v1.0/sectors")
    @ResponseStatus(OK)
    public Flux<SectorDto> getAllSectorsV1() {
        Flux<SectorEntity> sectors = sectorRepository.findAll();
        return sectors.map(sector -> modelMapper.map(sector, SectorDto.class));
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "v2.0/sectors")
    @ResponseStatus(OK)
    public Flux<SectorDto> getAllSectorsV2() {
        // New implementation goes here
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Although this will work, to my taste this looks like a hack with too much code repetition imo. I hoped there would be a more elegant solution. I would prefer not to remove the namespace from the controller annotation either.